# yii2 API input multiple records to one table

Tags: php, yii2

I'm going to make API for creating multiple records in one table.
This is my action in Controller

```
class RecorditemController extends Controller
{    
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        ];

        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionCreate()
    {        
        $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('Recorditem', []));       
        $products = [new Recorditem()];        
        for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) 
        {
            $products[] = new Recorditem();
        }        
        if (Model::loadMultiple($products, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($products)) {
            foreach ($products as $product) 
            {        
                $product->save(false);
            }
            return ['status' => 'true'];
        }
    }      

    public function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'create' => ['post'],
        ];
    }   
}
```

For testing I'm sending JSON in this way:

```
[
    {
        "food_id": 13,
        "quantity": 5,
        "order_id": 1
    },
    {
        "food_id": 13,
        "quantity": 6,
        "order_id": 1
    }
]
```

But my approach is not working. It returns nothing. Where is my mistake or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: How are you sending this values? What are you using at the client side (angular, vue, react, jquery)? Is it restfull?

Comment: you need to add how you are sending the request using `curl`? are there any request header that you are setting for `Content-Type`.

Comment: I have the feeling this is the same problem I recently had. The thing is that with this frameworks the request sends json data as a raw payload, so trying to use the yii2 load or loadMultiple should not work.
I am pretty sure that  @nuriddin-kamardinov will find the anwer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838923/how-to-process-vue-axios-json-payload-posted-data-on-yii2/50838924#50838924

Comment: The "returns nothing" gives it away... I bet the json its a plain raw payload hidden away from Yii2 at plain sight.

Comment: It is restfull api. Clients are smartphones. Thank you, @moplin. Your link helped me

Comment: Good to be of help. Please give the answer a vote if it helped.